# 802.1Q VLAN tagging seemingly ignored by switch

Tags: networking, ethernet, switch, vlan

I am trying to get hands-on familiarity with configuring VLAN (802.1Q). In my TL-SG108PE switch, I have tagged port 5 with VLAN 507 and also made port 6 part of that VLAN (untagged):

[image]

Port 6 is connected to a router which assigns IP addresses (DHCP).

Port 5 is connected to a Pi device running Debian 11, on which I am trying to get VLAN to work:

```
auto eth0.507
iface eth0.507 inet dhcp
```

But the Pi does not show up on the network (which is the ultimate issue I am trying to solve, but hang on, this question is different).

However, if I revert the Pi's network config back to the non-VLAN default:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

— it happily works like it is connected to a non-VLAN port on the switch!

How can that happen?

If my understanding is correct, since port 5 is tagged, the switch will add additional packet header to all packets going from it, and the Pi, not being configured to recognize VLAN 507, should *not* be able to connect.

So, why does the system behave like port 5 is non-VLAN?

Is it the case that the Pi simply ignores VLAN header on network packets and, so, recognizes them anyway?

Comment: You still have those two ports with VLAN 1 untagged, what happens if you remove that?

Comment: @user1686 VLAN 1 is non-removable (see the checkbox is disabled).

Comment: Sorry, correction, remove _port 6_ as member of that VLAN, leaving only 1-5 and 7-8 untagged. (Port 5 is fine.) Also, can you show the "802.1Q PVID" page? Have you changed the PVID of port 6 to match?

Comment: @user1686 Thanks for your hints, I just got it ALL to work! Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the router attempts to send an untagged packet (DHCP reply to your Pi), the switch will use that port's "PVID" setting as the implied VLAN tag. If you haven't changed the PVID of port 6 from the default yet, then untagged packets are assumed to belong to VLAN 1, not VLAN 507.

Also, port 6 has *two* untagged VLANs (both 1 and 507 are configured as untagged on the same port). This is not going to work properly – it means the router will be receiving DHCP requests from *both* VLANs and will not be able to distinguish them properly without the VLAN tags, nor will it be able to respond correctly to both of them.

In "802.1Q PVID Setting", make sure the PVID of port 6 is set to 507.

In "802.1Q VLAN", configure VLAN 1 to have port 6 as "not member", leaving only 1-5 and 7-8 untagged.

(Some switches enforce only one untagged VLAN per port and automatically set its PVID to match, but not all do.)